# How can I put Net::SSH into a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a rails model `Instance`, that represents an EC2 instance.

At the moment, every time I have a method that must SSH it, I have to set up Net::SSH everywhere I want to do it, which is a lot.

for example:

```
Net::SSH.start(ip, 'ubuntu', keys: "mykey.pem" ) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec "sudo chmod +x /tmp/provision.sh"
end
```

Is there a way I can factor the 'ssh' set up bit into the Instance model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about encapsulating it into a private method, and yielding the connenction to the calling place.

```
class Instance

  def chmod
    start do |ssh|
      ssh.exec "sudo chmod +x /tmp/provision.sh"
      # other operations on ssh
    end
  end

  private

    def start
      Net::SSH.start(ip, 'ubuntu', keys: "mykey.pem" ) do |ssh|
        yield ssh
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: That looks pretty cool actually, can I put multiple lines into the passed block (i.e. multiple ssh.exec commands)?

Comment: one question. what does 'start' represent and why is it necessary/important?